# How to get git diff output in files that has difference?

Tags: git, terminal, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I analyze `git diff` between **Head** commit and previous commit.

I have `git diff` output in **Terminal**. To correct unnecessary difference I need switching between **Sublime Text** and **Terminal**.

Is it possible to get output of `git diff` straight in files, that has difference?

In manner when you have git output, when you have `git merge` conflict between branches. When git put lines with differences straight in code and note name of commits like this

```
<<<<<<<
Changes made on the branch that is being merged into. In most cases,
this is the branch that I have currently checked out (i.e. HEAD).
|||||||
The common ancestor version.
=======
Changes made on the branch that is being merged in. This is often a 
feature/topic branch.
>>>>>>>
```

Comment: I do not understand your question... what you mean with "in files that has difference" ? You could make an small example what you exactly want.

Comment: @YesThatIsMyName Ok. I will do.

Comment: @YesThatIsMyName, I guess Erick wants some marker directly in the file that indicates with `<<<<<`, `=====` and `>>>>>` delimiters what has changed, like in merge conflicts. If I'm right, this can't be done as it would change the file again, thus generating other delimited sections, etc, etc In that case, Erick, you should change your question and ask for a SublimeText addon/plugin that does this.

Comment: Not sure of what you want to ask but you can try {git diff --patch --unified}, this will create a patch file with few lines of context as well. More info here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff